# SQL Injection with $db->query($sql)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following syntax to insert something into my SQL-Tables:

```
$db = @mysqli_connect("", "", "") or die("connection failed!");
mysqli_select_db($db,''); 
$user_stuff;
$sql = "INSERT INTO whatever ( ... ) VALUES (... '$user_stuff')";
$db->query($sql);
mysqli_close($db);
```

Is this save against SQL Injections? I am not sure how to use prepared statements here with that syntax? Or are these prepared statements already implemented inside of `->query(...)`???

Comment: Have you read the manual? Anyhow it's not safe against SQL injections because you're not doing anything with the user input. Use prepared statement, preferrably PDO.

Comment: good reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Its not about the query() method. It is about the query you put into it and how you build that query. (The $sql variable)

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)